# how do i find my default git password after installing git on raspbian (raspberry pi)

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, raspbian

I am trying to install Gogs on my RasPi 3 following this tutorial.
https://www.alexruf.net/2016/05/23/setup-gogs-git-service.html

After running the command `sudo apt-get install git` I have to create a user name git for running Gogs. However, when i try this i get the message that user git already exists.

When i change git for another name I get the prompt `[sudo] password for git:`

What is the password i should enter here? Its not the password of my raspbian pi, i already tried that. It must be a default password but i cant find anywhere what that default password is. Also i'm new to Linux/raspbian and installing programs on such an OS.

Could anyone give me a few pointers? I keep getting permission denied when i try to wget something or when i try to add a user.

Thanks in advance

Comment: git is a non-login user so it should not have a password. The question being what exactly are you trying to do ?

Comment: I am trying to execute the command sudo wget https://dl.gogs.io/gogs_v0.9.13_raspi2.zip in the terminal, when i do this it asks me for a git password

Comment: why do you want to sudo (I hope `git` is a **not** a sudoer )? You need to download your zipball (`wget http://things.tld/stuff.zip`), extract it (`unzip ./stuff.zip`), then change the ownership of the extracted content to the git user (`chown -R git:git ./stuff`). No need to be the `git` user to do this.

Comment: because else i get a permission denied message